# JSOUP automatically close my tag?

Tags: android, jsoup

I have a custom tag called some data that i wish to extract. However it seems to me that by doing the following code in android, it automatically remove my `</link>` and replace it onto the first  tag.

```
    Document document = Jsoup.parse("<html><head></head><body><link>test</link></body></html>");
            Log.e(Config.log_id, document.html());
```

The following code will result in `<html><head></head><body><link />test</body></html>`

once i did a .html. Any solution here?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid.  The 'link' tag is not allowed to have any content, so the parser is closing it implicitly and then ignoring your extraneous close tag.

Comment: Also, <link> is not allowed in the body. It must be placed inside the <head> tag.

Comment: haha it's actually not my html code, i'm just trying to extract those data from some rss. i solved by replacing the protected keyword. THX GUYS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems to be that the keyword link is used. I have to replace  to  before parsing and it worked.